# Mac OS X: How to get access to the PDF menu in the print dialog

Tags: macos, pdf, printing

I'd like to add an item to the PDF Menu in the standard print dialog. The menu in the lower left corner. I would like to have something like "Save PDF to My Great Application". It seems to be possible as I have found apps that do just that. But how? There is nothing I could find in the documentation.

[image: print dialog with PDF menu]

Does anyone know more? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your looking for is called `PDF printing workflows` and can be added using the `Edit Menu` option.

You can find out more in the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Printing/Conceptual/PDF_Workflow/pdfwf_concepts/pdfwf_concepts.html .

HTH

Comment: That's it! How could I have missed that? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it is not comparable with sandboxing unfortunately :(